# Factorizing blocks of code in C

Tags: c, menu

I'm stuck with a situation where my function is running on too many lines. Clearly there are repeating factors, I'm not sure how to factorize it just yet. I've tried putting the same codes into another function but it takes almost the same amount of code lines. Any better way to factorize it? Thanks.

```
int purchase_meal() {

    FILE *fptr;

    char meal_choice[5];
    char *item;
    float price, sumtax, tax;
    unsigned int quantity;
    float total=0, grand_total=0;

    while(strcmp(meal_choice, "-1") != 0) {

        printf("Please enter a meal order option and how many orders. Example: C0001 2 \n");
        scanf("%s %d", meal_choice, &quantity);

        if (meal_choice[0] == '-' && meal_choice[1] == '1') {
            print_receipt();
            order();
        } 
        else if (meal_choice[0] == 'C' && meal_choice[1] == '0' && meal_choice[2] == '0' && meal_choice[3] == '0') {
            fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a+"); //opens receipt txt file and appends
            if(fptr == NULL) //check whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            } 
            else {
                switch (meal_choice[4]) {
                    case '1':    // assuming they chose set 1 with code C0001
                        price = combo1.price;
                        item = combo1.name;
                        tax = taxing(combo1.price, quantity);
                        total = (combo1.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        csum.combo_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15d%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo1.name, combo1.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    case '2':
                        price = combo2.price;
                        item = combo2.name;
                        tax = taxing(combo2.price, quantity);
                        total = (combo2.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        csum.combo_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15d%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo2.name, combo2.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    case '3':
                        price = combo3.price;
                        item = combo3.name;
                        tax = taxing(combo3.price, quantity);
                        total = (combo3.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        csum.combo_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15d%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo3.name, combo3.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);


                        break;
                    case '4':
                        price = combo4.price;
                        item = combo4.name;
                        tax = taxing(combo4.price, quantity);
                        total = (combo4.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        csum.combo_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15d%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo4.name, combo4.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    case '5':
                        price = combo5.price;
                        item = combo5.name;
                        tax = taxing(combo5.price, quantity);
                        total = (combo5.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        csum.combo_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15d%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo5.name, combo5.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    default:
                        puts("Invalid meal option!");

                }
                fclose(fptr); //close the file
            }
        } 
        else if (meal_choice[0] == 'A' && meal_choice[1] == '0' && meal_choice[2] == '0' && meal_choice[3] == '0') {
            fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a"); //opens txt file and READS only
            if(fptr == NULL) //check whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            } else {
                switch (meal_choice[4]) {
                    case '1':  // assuming they chose set 1 with code C0001 
                        price = addon1.price;
                        item = addon1.name;
                        tax = taxing(addon1.price, quantity);
                        total = (addon1.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon1.name, addon1.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    case '2':
                        price = addon2.price;
                        item = addon2.name;
                        tax = taxing(addon2.price, quantity);
                        total = (addon2.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon2.name, addon2.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    case '3':
                        price = addon3.price;
                        item = addon3.name;
                        tax = taxing(addon3.price, quantity);
                        total = (addon3.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon3.name, addon3.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);


                        break;
                    case '4':
                        price = addon4.price;
                        item = addon4.name;
                        tax = taxing(addon4.price, quantity);
                        total = (addon4.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon4.name, addon4.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    case '5':
                        price = addon5.price;
                        item = addon5.name;
                        tax = taxing(addon5.price, quantity);
                        total = (addon5.price * quantity) + tax;
                        grand_total += total;
                        sumtax += tax;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        sum.total = grand_total;
                        sum.tax = sumtax;

                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon5.name, addon5.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);

                        break;
                    default:
                        puts("Invalid meal option!");

                }
                fclose(fptr); //close the file
            } //end else for file found
        } //end else for menu option A or C
    } //end of while loop

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the code work? If so, consider posting on [codereview.se]. Also C != C++. Pick one.

Comment: Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help With that knowledge there is something obvious you can improve in yoru answer.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) do not insert random blank lines

Comment: reguarding: `fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a+"); //opens receipt txt file and appends
            if(fptr == NULL) //check whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            }`  error messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout`,  When the error is from a system function, also output the related text message.  After a 'unfixable' error, cleanup and exit the program. Suggest: replace: `printf("File cannot be found\n");` with: `perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow.  Such buffer overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this line: `while(strcmp(meal_choice, "-1") != 0) {`  the array is being used before it has been initialized/set to a known contents.  Accessing an uninitialized array is undefined behavior

Comment: please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `printf("Please enter a meal order option and how many orders. Example: C0001 2 \n");`  no menu has been displayed to the user, so the user has no idea what a "meal order option" means.  Strongly suggest displaying a actual menu And suggest each menu option be a single letter.  That would simplify how the user interacts with the program and the code that checks on each menu option.

Comment: the user is never told that exiting the program is via entering a '-1' for the menu option AND the user will still have to enter a 'number of orders' value as this: `scanf("%s %d", meal_choice, &quantity);` will not be completed until both variables have been entered by the user.   Suggest using two calls to `scanf()`

Comment: the posted code is missing a `main()` function.  the posted code is missing the `print_receipt()` function.  the posted code is missing the `print_order()` function.  the posted code is missing the `#include` statements.

Comment: strongly suggest separating the handling of the 'A' and 'C' menu options into separate functions

Comment: regarding: `fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a"); //opens txt file and READS only` this is NOT opening the file for 'read only'  rather, it is opening the file to append more text at the end of the file

Comment: the user is not informed that the menu choice has to be exactly 4 characters.  Regarding: `switch (meal_choice[4])`  The array 'menu_choice' is exactly 5 characters in length so valid indexing into that array is 0...4  So this statement is accessing the very last character of the array, which will be a '\0'. so the only code that will be executed after that statement is: `default: puts("Invalid meal option!");`

Comment: the array `combo5` is not defined in the posted code.  The array 'csum' is not defined in the posted code.  The array 'sum' is not defined in the posted code.

Comment: the code sequence: `fprintf(fptr, "%-15d%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo5.name, combo5.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);` could (probably) be extracted from each 'case' and inserted after the end of the related 'switch()' statement, probably with a check to assure the user had entered a valid value

Comment: the function: `order()` is missing from the posted code.

Comment: this code block: ` while(strcmp(meal_choice, "-1") != 0) {

        printf("Please enter a meal order option and how many orders. Example: C0001 2 \n");
        scanf("%s %d", meal_choice, &quantity);

        if (meal_choice[0] == '-'
            && meal_choice[1] == '1')
        {
            print_receipt();
            order();
        }`  would be better written with: `while(1)`  and `...order(); break;`

Comment: the statement: `switch( menu_choice[4] )` and all the following `case` code blocks are exactly the same,  so that switch statement and all the following `case` statements can replace with and 'if()' statement,the contents of any one of the `case` code blocks and an 'else' code block with the contents of the 'default' code block   The result will\ greatly shrink the code lines

Comment: suggest all the `combo#` data structs be organized as an array and use the `menu_choice[4]` to index into the `combo#` array/  Similar considerations exist for the accessing of the 'addon#` data entries being organized as an array

Comment: what happens if the user enters other than 'A000#'  or 'C000#"?

Comment: this comment: "// assuming they chose set 1 with code C0001 " is not enforced in the code.  Suggest making the code more sequential so as to enforce  this assumption.

Comment: suggest only opening the output file once, at the beginning of the posted code, and only close it once, when the user entered '-1'

Comment: Given the above comments,  The code 'can' be greatly shortened.  However, it would be MUCH better, for flexibility and ease of understanding to handle each event (user input) in a separate function.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s %d", meal_choice, &quantity);`  the array 'meal_choice' is only 5 characters long.  and `scanf()` always appends a NUL character when handling the '%s' input/conversion specifier.  So if the user enters (for instance) "A0001" The input buffer 'menu_choice' will be overflowed.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( 2 != scanf("%4s %d", meal_choice, &quantity) ) { perror( "scanf failed" );  // cleanup then exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  // implied else, scanf successful`

Answer (score 0):

So this was the best I could, to refactor, by placing the sums at the end of the switch statements. Yes, the validation works for not not accepting invalid meal codes such as other than C0001, C0002, C0003, C0004, C0005, A0001, A0002, A0003, A0004, A0005 (if you are wondering what are the meal codes), however if user input is float, it will cause an infinity loop which I'm still working on. I've also added the info to exit loop with sentinel value of -1. Thank you everyone for the kind feedback.

```
int purchase_meal() {

    FILE *fptr; //flie pointer for receipt text file
    char meal_choice[5]; //user input meal code
    char *item;
    float price;
    unsigned int quantity=0;    
    float total=0, grand_total=0;   

    while(strcmp(meal_choice, "-1") != 0) {     
        printf("Please enter a meal order option (-1 to exit). Example: C0001.\n");     
        scanf("%s", meal_choice);

        if (meal_choice[0] == '-' && meal_choice[1] == '1') {           
            print_receipt();                
            order();
        } 
        else if (strlen(meal_choice) == 5 && meal_choice[0] == 'C' && meal_choice[1] == '0' && meal_choice[2] == '0' && meal_choice[3] == '0'){
            printf("Enter quantity of order. \n");
            scanf("%d", &quantity);

            fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a+"); //opens receipt txt file and appends
            if(fptr == NULL) //check whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            } 
            else {              
                switch (meal_choice[4]) {                                           
                    case '1':           // assuming they chose set 1 with code C0001                
                        price = combo1.price;               
                        item = combo1.name;                                         
                        total = combo1.price * quantity;
                        grand_total += total;                       
                        csum.combo_trans++;
                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo1.name, combo1.price);                  
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        price = combo2.price;
                        item = combo2.name;                     
                        total = combo2.price * quantity;
                        grand_total += total;                       
                        csum.combo_trans++;                                                                             
                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo2.name, combo2.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                            
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        price = combo3.price;
                        item = combo3.name;                     
                        total = combo3.price * quantity;
                        grand_total += total;                   
                        csum.combo_trans++;                                                                                         
                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo3.name, combo3.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                            
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        price = combo4.price;
                        item = combo4.name;                     
                        total = combo4.price * quantity;
                        grand_total += total;                       
                        csum.combo_trans++;                         
                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo4.name, combo4.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                        
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        price = combo5.price;
                        item = combo5.name;                     
                        total = combo5.price * quantity;
                        grand_total += total;                       
                        csum.combo_trans++;                                                             
                        fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-27s%-17.2f\n", quantity, combo5.name, combo5.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                        
                        break;           
                    default:
                        total =0;                                                                   
                }                   
                fclose(fptr); //close the file              
            }       
        } 
        else if (strlen(meal_choice) == 5 && meal_choice[0] == 'A' && meal_choice[1] == '0' && meal_choice[2] == '0' && meal_choice[3] == '0') {
            printf("Enter quantity of order. \n");
            scanf("%d", &quantity);

            fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a"); //opens txt file and READS only
            if(fptr == NULL) //check whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            } else {                
                switch (meal_choice[4]) {                                           
                    case '1':           // assuming they chose set 1 with code C0001 
                        price = addon1.price;               
                        item = addon1.name;                                 
                        total = addon1.price * quantity;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        grand_total += total;                                                                                                                           
                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon1.name, addon1.price);                   
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        price = addon2.price;
                        item = addon2.name;                     
                        total = addon2.price * quantity;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        grand_total += total;                                                                                                                                   
                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon2.name, addon2.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                            
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        price = addon3.price;
                        item = addon3.name;                     
                        total = addon3.price * quantity;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        grand_total += total;                                                                                                   
                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon3.name, addon3.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                            
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        price = addon4.price;
                        item = addon4.name;                     
                        total = addon4.price * quantity;                        
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        grand_total += total;                                                                                                   
                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon4.name, addon4.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                        
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        price = addon5.price;
                        item = addon5.name;                     
                        total = addon5.price * quantity;
                        asum.ala_trans++;
                        grand_total += total;                                                                                                           
                        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t%s\t\t\t%.2f\n", quantity, addon5.name, addon5.price);
                        print_order(quantity, item, price, grand_total);                        
                        break;           
                    default:
                        total =0;                                                   
                }       
                fclose(fptr); //close the file                                              
            } //end else for file found         
        } else {
            quantity = 0; //declare quantity 0 because to prevent dummy data
            price = 0; //declare price of certain order 0 because to prevent added into total
            total =0; //declare total in order 0 because to prevent added into grand total
            printf("Invalid meal code. \n");
        } //end else for menu option A or C         
        sum.total = grand_total;
        sum.grand_total += total;                   
    } //end of while loop       
    return 0;
}
```